# Firebase key default value

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I come from a 10 years SQL Server background, where I'm used to set a default value of GetDate() on a field, e.g. when I need to know the server date/time when the record was inserted.

I'd like to take the same approach to Firebase, maybe by using rules, but I don't understand how and if it is possible.

I read some valueable suggestions like the following

[The 2^120 Ways to Ensure Unique Identifiers](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html)

In any case it seems that some code needs to be executed on the client side.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance, regards

Comment: You want to fill a field in the database with the server time? For that you can use a [server value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue)

Comment: Sounds like an answer Andre. :-)

Comment: Thanks Andrè, it is just what I am doing, and maybe it is the way to go. My question was if I could replicate the MS SQL Server way of default values with function, e.g. GetDate() to get the server datetime.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking for the server timestamp firebase comes with this built in.

```
firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

[Here is the info from Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue)